# Laravel - Directly Acess PHP without this framework

Tags: laravel

I'am using Laravel framework and i have some problem, i want some file php running without laravel framework because when running using laravel running too slow.

**For Example In Localhost:**

- I have framework laravel in 'store' folder
- I want to access directly php file in folder 'store/test/test.php'

And one more, how to implement to hosting ? it same ? thankyou.

Comment: I've never tried it but I think you may be able to put your php file in the `public` folder and access it from there? e.g. `127.0.0.1/test.php`. I don't know why it would be slow in Laravel and fine elsewhere. An alternative to the first option would be to create a route to a controller action and having all of your logic in it.

Comment: I use looping to much and i using CURL to scrape some data, that why i cannot use laravel for some how explanation, however i have been tryed using CURL scraping from laravel and it so so bad than i using php native.

Comment: You can put your files in public folder or where you have your index.php file

Comment: i have try but return error 'localhost refush to connect'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your folder inside public folder and add your file inside your folder and run your url like `yourroute/yourfile.php`

Comment: i have try but return error 'localhost refush to connect'

Comment: then add your file in public folder diractoly and run with your file nameyourroute/yourfile.php